# Return Value to header in every page Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a header in every page, the header has member id. I created `header.blade.php` , and included in `default.blade.php` , which is something like this:

`default.blade.php`

```
<header>
    @include('includes.header')
</header>
```

I need to pass member id from `controller.php` to `header.blade.php` , this is the problem. How to do it?

Comment: Any attempts, trials to show us your efforts?

Comment: Have you tried to extend Blade? http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/templates#extending-blade

Answer (score 4):

I suggest using a [view composer](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/views#view-composers). This will allow you to define/assign a variable into any given template on any request. For the sake of demonstration, I'll assume your "member id" is 5. You'd need to create a service provider, I've copied this from the docs:

```
<?php namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class ComposerServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    /**
     * Register bindings in the container.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        // Using Closure based composers...
        View::composer('includes.header', function($view)
        {
            return $view->with('memberId', 5);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Register
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

}
```

You will need to register this service provider in `config/app.php`. Once you have done this, the variable `$memberId` will be available in your header template. `{{ $memberId }}`

Comment: this view controller is in app/controllers? I put it in app/controllers, added config in config/app.php, refresh page, error : something wrong, checked error log but no error. btw, im using laravel 4.2 :)

Comment: This approach should work in 4.2. However, you can just copy the code out of boot, the "View::composer()", and place it in your routes.php. You won't need the rest of the code in the example.